# Proper way to handle prism navigation exception

Tags: wpf, prism, dryioc

I am using *Prism Wpf 8.1.97, and DryIoc container*.

In my scenario i have to navigate between two views, so I implemented the **INavigationAware** Interface provided by Prism Framework in my viewModels.

I call the **IRegionManager RequestNavigate** method to perform the navigation from the VMA to VMB.

Unfortunately, I forgot to register a IService dependency that is needed in the VMB Ctor, so when I perform the navigation process I get the exception in the navigation callback.

The IService interface

```
    public interface IService
    {

    }
```

ViewModel A:

```
public class ViewAViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
    {
        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

        public ViewAViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            this.regionManager = regionManager;
        }

        public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            regionManager.TryRequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViewB", new NavigationParameters());
        }

        public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            return true;
        }

       public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {

        }
```

}

ViewModelB:

```
 public class ViewBViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
        {
            public ViewBViewModel(IService service)
            {
    
            }
    
            public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
            {
                return true;
            }
    
            public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
            {
              
            }
    
        public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
            {
               
            }
        }
```

I created an extension method to keep it simple..

```
public static class IRegionManager_Extensions
{
    public static void TryRequestNavigate(this IRegionManager regionManager, string regionName, string target, NavigationParameters navigationParameters)
    {
        regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName, target, NavigationResult =>
        {
            if (NavigationResult.Result == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(NavigationResult.Error.InnerException.Message, "Navigation Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }, navigationParameters);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately what I get from the **InnerException.Message** is

> ContainerException: code: Error.UnableToResolveFromRegisteredServices;
> message: Unable to resolve Resolution root
> Module1.ViewModels.ViewBViewModel   from container without scope  with
> Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients,
> UseDynamicRegistrationsAsFallbackOnly, FuncAndLazyWithoutRegistration,
> SelectLastRegisteredFactory} and without
> {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient,
> UseFastExpressionCompilerIfPlatformSupported}  with
> FactorySelector=SelectLastRegisteredFactory  with
> Made={FactoryMethod=ConstructorWithResolvableArguments}   with normal
> and dynamic registrations:   (DefaultDynamicKey(0), {FactoryID=178,
> ImplType=Module1.ViewModels.ViewBViewModel, Reuse=TransientReuse,
> HasCondition})

without no reference to "IService"

I need to show that the navigation failed because IService implementation is not found in the container.

**Is there a way to get the missing service Interface name from the exception?**

[**Service name** in the exception **is null**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY97e.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want and what do you get and what do you expect? The screenshot you posted looks _exactly_ like the DryIoc-docs

Comment: I edited the question, maybe now is more clear.. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a DryIoc problem, actually - when removing the `WithConcreteTypeDynamicRegistrations` rule I get the expected message in the exception (along the lines of `Unable to resolve BlankApp5.IDependency as parameter "dependency"`)

Comment: For reference, there's an [issue on Github](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/issues/506) now.

Comment: @Haukinger on it.

Comment: @AlessandroGaspani with the issue solved on DryIoc's side, I suggest you create an issue with Prism for them to upgrade their DryIoc-package and use the meaningful exception

Comment: @Haukinger Thanks!! https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/discussions/2722